# Java: How to create an Exception Hashtable?

Tags: java, exception, hashtable

At the suggestion of my professor, I am attempting to create an Exception Hashtable to be used in my Service Exceptions class. I am currently having a problem creating the values within my Hashtable.

So far, I have tried not creating variables, but this lead to my Exception being unable to be resolved. I've created variables, but they need to be instantiated, however, null results in a `NullPointException` and = new Exception() results in (example) `"e1=java.lang.Exception"`.

```
public class HashtableException {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Hashtable <String, Exception> exceptionHashtable = 
           new Hashtable <String, Exception>();

    Exception FileNotFoundException;
    Exception IOException;
    Exception ObjectStreamException;
    Exception ClassNotFoundException;
    Exception FileFormatException;
    Exception NoSuchFieldException;

    exceptionHashtable.put("e1", FileNotFoundException); 
    exceptionHashtable.put("e2", IOException); 
    exceptionHashtable.put("e3", ObjectStreamException); 
    exceptionHashtable.put("e4", ClassNotFoundException); 
    exceptionHashtable.put("e5", FileFormatException); 
    exceptionHashtable.put("e6", NoSuchFieldException); 


    System.out.println("The Hashtable is:" + exceptionHashtable);

  } // end main method
} // end class HashtableException
```

Displaying the Hashtable should have resulted in:

```
The Hashtable is:{e1=FileNotFoundException, e2=IOException,...}
```

but the actual output was:

```
The Hashtable is:{e6=java.lang.Exception, e5=java.lang.Exception,...}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to store in the table and how will you use it later? If it's just for printing it like that, then why not make it a `Hashtable<String, String>`?

Comment: FileNotFoundException, IOException, ... in your code are variables of the class Exception that just happen to have the same name as some classes that inherit from Exception. You would need to create objects of the specific class, not from the Exception class.

Comment: I am creating an application and want to store the exceptions to be able to call them in my Service Exceptions and ServiceImpl classes. I have used <String, Exception) because I was trying to maintain the Exception "background" instead of just a string. But that is certainly interesting. Maybe that's a more realistic approach...?

Comment: So I've gone in and changed the value names, however, they are still asking to be instantiated, which results in the previously mentioned errors when instantiated and if not instantiated.

Comment: I apologize as I am still new to Java, but is there a way to instead make the Hashtable<String, String> and "associate" each variable with its class Exception counterpart?

Comment: @NoblestArgon `exceptionHashtable.put("e1", FileNotFoundException.class.getSimpleName())`

Comment: Thank you! That is incredibly helpful! :)

Comment: What is it that you're trying to actually get done? Note that (1) you should never use `Hashtable` as it's been obsolete for 20+ years (read its documentation), and (2) you should never "cache" and reuse exceptions because that will provide misleading error reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code to the following and it works now. However, two of them did not work so I have commented. You need to figure out what needs to be done with them

```
        FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException= new FileNotFoundException();
        IOException ioException = new IOException();
        //ObjectStreamException objectStreamException = null;
        ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException= new ClassNotFoundException();
        //FileFormatException FileFormatException;
        NoSuchFieldException noSuchFieldException  = new NoSuchFieldException();

        exceptionHashtable.put("e1", fileNotFoundException); 
        exceptionHashtable.put("e2", ioException); 
        //exceptionHashtable.put("e3", objectStreamException); 
        exceptionHashtable.put("e4", classNotFoundException); 
        //exceptionHashtable.put("e5", FileFormatException); 
        exceptionHashtable.put("e6", noSuchFieldException); 


        System.out.println("The Hashtable is:" + exceptionHashtable);
```

The output is

The Hashtable is:{e6=java.lang.NoSuchFieldException, e4=java.lang.ClassNotFoundException, e2=java.io.IOException, e1=java.io.FileNotFoundException}

Comment: Please do not do people's homework for them: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework  - We want to teach people to fish, not just give them a fish sandwich.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I will address the two that do not produce an output. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Because you're asking for help with homework, I'm going to give vague but (hopefully) helpful hints and general explanations.

A variable is a bucket that can hold something.  When you use a variable in an expression, you are asking the thing in the bucket to do some task for you.

When the bucket is empty, it doesn't contain anything.  Trying to use that bucket to do work is meaningless, because you're really asking the thing in the bucket - *nothing*.  `null` means the bucket doesn't contain anything, and if you try to do something with it (other than check for `null`) then you get a `NullPointerException`.

You are also confusing the *name* of your variables with the *type*.  Naming a variable 'IOException' doesn't mean it actually is an `IOException`.  You have created a variable whose type is `Exception` with a name that will confuse anyone looking at it about what type of variable it is.  Since you seem to want to refer to the class `IOException`, try looking here: [the class Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) and also at [class literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).